# currentCultureName vs currentUICultureName

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-addin

What is the difference between `_spPageContextInfo.currentCultureName` and `_spPageContextInfo.currentUICultureName`.

`_spPageContextInfo.currentCultureName` was not working for me and i tried the other one and it showed the correct language. But I am trying to understand the difference between these two items and which one is more reliable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
_spPageContextInfo.currentUICultureName
```

is the culture used to determine UI's language (Language used in the website's menus)

```
_spPageContextInfo.currentCultureName
```

is the culture used for numbers/date formatting...

http://sprecipe.com/2016/02/08/_sppagecontextinfo-difference-between-currentculturename-and-currentuiculturename/

Comment: thanks, any msdn reference available?

Comment: Unfortunately I could not find any reference from Microsoft...  Instead of just listing all properties, this website (in chinese) displays for every property which is the corresponding object in .Net http://code.qtuba.com/article-11837.html (they used reflector to find this)

Comment: @SylvainGantois link is broken